# Object cloning with cyclic reference chain

Tags: c#, clone, directed-graph, cyclic-reference

I'm running some operations on a graph in memory, which modify the graph itself. I need to repeat these operations some number of times, and subsequent repetitions must work on a fresh copy of the graph. Since the graph is generated by parsing a file, I don't really want to spend time re-parsing the file for every repetition, so I've gone down the route of cloning the original graph.

My `node`, `edge` and `graph` types are all implementing `ICloneable`, but I have an issue with a cyclic reference chain.

`Node` stores a list of directed `Edge`s coming from it. `Edge` stores the weight and the `Node` it points to. When two nodes share a bi-directional edge, I get a `StackOverflowException` when I attempt to clone either node, since cloning the list of edges of either node invariably means cloning the other node.

What would be the best approach to resolve this cyclic reference for the purposes of cloning?

Comment: Are you *sure* that the parsing is a real bottleneck?  Have you profiled an implementation that simply re-parsed each time and validated that the parsing represents the portion of your logic that consumes the most CPU resources?